# Bash issue with unexpected token

Tags: bash, ipv6

The script below seems to work when I run it on its own in vscode it says literal carriage return on the second and third line.

When I put it into a larger script I get this issue

```
./script.sh: line 64: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
./script.sh: line 64: `ipv6address=$(hostname -I | cut -d " " -f 2)'
```

Can any one advise please

```
#!/bin/bash
ipv6address=$(hostname -I | cut -d " " -f 2)
tee -a <<EOF >/dev/null "$HOME"/ipv6
[network]
# replace the ip with yours
routable_ip ="$ipv6address"
EOF
```

Comment: To get first IPv6 of host: `ip -6 -json a s scope global | jq -r '.[0].addr_info[0].local'`

Comment: The reported syntax error is on line 64, but you don't indicate, which line this would be. I guess the error is in something inside your HERE document. The line `ipv6address=$(hostname -I | cut -d " " -f 2)` itself is syntactically valid.